# plotting a bias/variance/error trade-off in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create the following graphic in LaTeX/tikz. I am able to plot the convex "Total Error" line but I cannot seem to complete the graphic. I want to show the bias/variance trade-off in Machine Learning models.

Any help/push in the right direction would be appreciated.

How can I replicate the following plot?

[image]

Comment: Hi, please attach a MWE (minimal work example), i.e. a full compilable code of your try. Anyway the pgfplots package will provide what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this.

[image]

```
% Adapted from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/master/tikz/bias-variance/bias-variance.tex
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{>=stealth,
OptimumStyle/.style={align=center,anchor=east,rotate=90,font=\sffamily\scriptsize}
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,
samples=101,
axis lines = left,
every axis plot/.append style={line width=2pt},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin= 0,     
        xmax= 2,    
        ymin= 0,     
        ymax= 2,   
        xlabel=Model Complexity,
        ylabel=Error,
        ticks=none,
        xticklabels={\empty},
        yticklabels={\empty}
    ]
      \addplot[domain=0.2:1.9,Maroon,<->] {1/(x+0.3)-0.2};   %Bias
      \addplot[domain=0.2:1.9,TealBlue,<->] {0.12*e^(1.40*x)};   %Variance
      \addplot[domain=0.39:1.61,black,<->] {3*(x-2)*x+3.8};  %Total error
      \addplot[dotted,thin] coordinates {(1,0) (1,2)};       %Optimum model complexity
      \node[OptimumStyle] at (axis cs:0.9,2) {Optimum Model\\Complexity};
      \node[anchor=south west,text=Maroon] at (axis cs:1.4,0.4){Bias\textsuperscript{2}};
      \node[anchor=north west,text=TealBlue] at (axis cs:1.4,0.85){Variance};
      \node[anchor=south east,align=center] at (axis cs:1.5,1.5){Total\\error};
      \legend{}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```